# javascript function is not working ( no errors )

Tags: javascript

hi i have javascript issue that i wrote a input when i change it text to sadra it doesn't alert "your text contains "sadra"  word " how can i resolve it ? thanks for helping ...

here is the code:

```js
var realText;

function text(realText) {
  var realText = document.getElementById('input1').innerHTML;
  if (realText.includes('sadra')) {
    alert("your text contains \"sadra\"  word ");
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Input :</label>
<input type="text" name="test" id="input1" onchange="text(realText)" />
```

Comment: input's don't have `innerHTML` they have a `value`

Comment: You are overriding a function parameter within the function itself, which is bad practice. If you are getting the value of the input field with a selector you don't need the parameter here at all

Comment: There's also no point in that global `var realText`, the `realText` function parameter or passing `realText` in `onchange`. You can remove all those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to access the `value` inside the element with id `input1`, then the selector should point to `value` of the node.

```
document.getElementById('input1').value
```

Also there is no need to pass the `realText` parameter to the `onchange` event. This is not going to have an impact on the functionality.

`innerHTML` gives the `html` code inside a specified id

**`innerHTML` Example**

```js
function text() {
  var realText = document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;
  console.log('Inner HTML', realText);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <label>Input :</label>
  <input type="text" name="test" id="input1" onchange="text()" />
</div>
```

**Your Working fiddle**

```js
function text() {
  var realText = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  if (realText.includes('sadra')) {
    alert("your text contains \"sadra\"  word ");
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Input :</label>
<input type="text" name="test" id="input1" onchange="text()" />
```